# Giving an explicit example of a vector that is perpendicular to $v$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$ be a unit vector. It is possible to show that there exists vectors $\{w_1,w_2\}$ such that $\{v,w_1,w_2\}$ is orthonormal by applying the [Gram-Schmidt process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), but can we do so *continuously*?

**Question:** Is it possbile to give these vectors explicitly
? More precisely: Can someone give examples of continuous functions $f,g:\mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ such that for every unit vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the set $\{v,f(v),g(v)\}$ is orthonormal ?

To solve the above question, it suffices to find a continuous function $h:\mathbb{R}^3-\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3-\{0\}$ such that for every nonzero vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^3$, we have $h(v)\cdot v=0$. Once one finds this function we can set $f(v)=\frac{h(v)}{||h(v)||},g(v)=\frac{v\times h(v)}{||v\times h(v)||}$. I spent some time to find such a function, but I didn't find any. In case this impossible, I am guessing it would be due to something about the topology of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Thus, I am tagging this question as general topology as well.

Thank you

Comment: Interestingly: What I am trying to do is possible for $\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know the 'hairy ball theorem', that you can't have a continuous non-zero vector field on the surface of the sphere?  The vector pointing from $v$ to $f(v)$ would be that field.

Comment: No. I don't. Thanks for your answer. I will search for it now

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem#Application_to_computer_graphics has a similar problem to the one I was trying to solve